# Question marks after images and js/css files in rails. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know why there are question marks (with a number) after the images and css files (when looking at the html code)? And how can I turn them off?

Comment: Please give more details on your problem, as I can't really understand what is the problem and where does it appear. Some example would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html):

> By default, Rails will append all
>   asset paths with that asset‘s
>   timestamp. This allows you to set a
>   cache-expiration date for the asset
>   far into the future, but still be able
>   to instantly invalidate it by simply
>   updating the file (and hence updating
>   the timestamp, which then updates the
>   URL as the timestamp is part of that,
>   which in turn busts the cache).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is to be able to cache the file on the client and still making sure the client receive the newest version when there is a change. So each file modification results in a new timestamp which the client will do a new request to the server to receive the modified file.

If you do not want to use (though I cannot see why - it is a good thing) simple do not use the rails helpers for including javascripts or stylesheets. Just include the normal HTML tags: link and script.