# What does "html?v=<%= VERSION %>" mean?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I'm having a difficult time finding the answer.
Basically, what is the `?v=<%= VERSION %>` doing on the following line?

```
'./components/home/home.html?v=<%= VERSION %>
```

If it helps, the source file can be seen [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/app/components/home/home.ts).

Or here:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-1'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/home/home.html?v=<%= VERSION %>',
  directives: [RouterLink]
})
export class Home {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question marks after images and js/css files in rails. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374127/question-marks-after-images-and-js-css-files-in-rails-why)

Comment: Duplicate is about a different language, but it's the same answer and reason.

Comment: Is this within an ASP.NET project?

Comment: @pep: No, I simply cloned the project and installed it via npm as shown in the [instructions](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed).

Comment: @Paulpro: I see why you marked this as a duplicate now. I didn't know about `cache busting`. However, the syntax seems to be from ASP.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this really is ASP-alike, hence being a short for the `Response.Write` method.

```
<%= VERSION %>
```

equals

```
<%
Response.Write(VERSION)
%>
```

This line is using this "write" to control the template version.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't familiar with the ASP.net syntax.

Comment: Just wanted to added that although correct, this IS a common trick for cache busting. See link provided by basarat. Best regards

Answer (score 3):

> ?v=<%= VERSION %>

A common trick for *cache busting*.

A quick google result on the topic : http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/expiring.html